# Adding mods around a TP4506 (Led indicator + use load while USB plugged)

Tags: zener, lipo, load, charge, tp4056

This is my first post here, I'm looking to achieve some modification on my GBZ power part.
I'm currently using:

- LiPo Battery 3.7V 4000mAh
- Micro USB charger TP4056
- MT5608 Volt Booster (output 5V)

I'd like to add something to this:

Being able to use load while plugging power source to TP4056 (using a zener diode and a bypass for load):
[Is it ok to charge a battery with TP4056 while using it, if](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/520170/is-it-ok-to-charge-a-battery-with-tp4056-while-using-it-if)

I'm not sure I got it right, I also don't know what Voltage should I aim for the zener diode part.
I read that a 3.7V battery should be charged if reaching bellow (so starting from 3.6V)
does that mean I should get a 1W 3.6V zener ?

My schema also include adding a LED to warn about low battery (best would be a color changing led (from green to yellow, then orange, then red for example) but I only found this which is already cool:
https://www.sudomod.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=1107&start=40

Here's the schema I made, but I'm not sure I'm right, hence why I need some help from expert (I'm no electronics expert)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/33cIi.png]
Is this OK, or am I going to explode ?

Thank you for your time, and have a great day!

Comment: There's no way we can know how your charger module works, as we don't even know what module it is. What you are basically is "can I wire these random parts together like this". You need the datasheets and manuals for each device how to use them and connect them together, which basically boils down to a question of "how to use these electronic products".

Comment: It is not wise to assume you have any surplus to drive a load and also start up the charger.

Answer (score 0):

You ask if you can make changes to the circuit while it is powered. My answer is maybe but a lot depends on your knowledge, skill set and the tools you have available. My honest opinion is you do not have the knowledge or skill set required to make the changes.